# Node doesn't receive specific web hook

Tags: node.js, webhooks

I have a quite empty Node running so I can parse, manipulate and reroute web hooks, but I am having problem with one in specific that doesn't log on my Node.

The route used is this:

```
app.post("/stripe-webhooks-endpoint", bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/json'}), function(req, res) {
 console.log(req.body);
 res.send("Stripe Successfully received Webhook request");
});
```

When I test it with Postman, I receive a {} as log, and then it hits back on webhooksite like so:
[from postman to note and then webooksite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltOMC.png).
But when I try this one from another platform, it shows nothing on my node. When I send from that platform direct to Webhooksite, it is delivered like so:
[from external platform direct to webhooksite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mrTw.png).
Why would it be happening? Is there a better way to debug it?

Comment: Stipe has a nice interface that shows you all the webhook calls attempts with relative responses and errors, could you manage to gather more information on the issue there?